# Python Soundcloud api - redirect module not found error?

Tags: python, redirect, module, soundcloud, nameerror

I am new to this website and I was just wondering, does anyone know why am I getting this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/~/Downloads/soundcloud-python-master/DEAD.py", line 9, in <module>
NameError: name 'redirect' is not defined
```

for this chunk of code and how I can fix this?

```
import soundcloud

client = soundcloud.Client(
    client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET,
    redirect_uri='http://yourapp.com/callback'
)
redirect(client.authorize_url())
```

P.S. This chunk is straight off sound cloud's python git hub, so I am not exactly sure how I can get this to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but it may be the redirect found in flask. Information can be found here: http://flask.pocoo.org.

Good luck.